# Call one function after another in function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions ,function1() and function2() . Below is the structure of code

```
function1(){
 //Inside this function there is one more function(present in different JS file)
  functionA(){ //functionA calls a different function in some other JS file

  } 
}

function2(){

}
```

I tried giving call back so function1() will be executed before function2(). This didn't work.

Can anyone suggest. How can I execute function1()(all the functions inside the function) and then function2()?

Comment: What do these 2 functions do?  Are they making AJAX calls?  How did you attempt to use a callback?

Comment: Depending on what they do, you might want to look into using jQuery's deferred object/promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is vague but I'm assuming you're doing an async operation and it need to wait for a return something like this:

```
function1(callback){
   // last function called
 functionA(callback){ 
      // some ajax or async operation
      $.ajax(function(){ }).done(callback)
  } 
}

function2() {};

function1(function2)
```

If however there are multiple ajax calls and you need it to be done last you will have to chain all of the calls together or you will have to make a synchronization mechanism to call once all of the ajax calls have returned.

Comment: Yes correct I have AJAX call. I was callback inside function1 instead of functionA. Hence the issue. Thanks for the solution

Comment: did this work? If not let me know how I can help, if so please mark the question as answered

Answer (score -1):

You can return the second function and then call.

```
function fn1(){

    return function fn2(){
    }

}

fn1()()
```